# Simplifying the expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an expression and I don't know how to simplify it. Can anyone please help?

$$(a^2/2(4n^2-8n+4)) + (2n^2 - 2n + 1 (1+ a^2 \sqrt{1}))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if I am wrong, but I have a feeling you may have written that expression incorrectly; there isn't much *simplifying* you could do, though you could certainly combine some terms. For example, look at the left hand term: 
$$(a^2/2(4n^2-8n+4))$$

Is the $4n^2-8n+4$ in the denominator, or the numerator? Is it $(a^2/2)$*($4n^2-8n+4),$ or $$(a^2/(2(4n^2-8n+4))?$$

Assuming the former, here's what you could do:

$$(a^2/2(4n^2-8n+4)) + (2n^2 - 2n + 1 (1+ a^2 \sqrt{1}))$$

$$(a^2/2)4(n^2-2n+1) + (2n^2 - 2n) +  1+ a^2 $$

$$2a^2(n-1)^2 + 2n(n-1) +  1+ a^2 $$
$$(n-1)[2a^2(n-1)+ 2n]+  1+ a^2 $$
$$2(n-1)[a^2(n-1)+ n]+  1+ a^2 $$

As you could see, the new form isn't that much shorter to write. If you are sure that you typed in the problem correctly, then here's your answer. However, if you misplaced a parenthesis, you might want to fix that quickly- your answer can differ immensely.